# glaux.lib in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, opengl, porting

I'm porting some code from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008.

Can i use the glaux.lib found in Visual Studio 2005 found in \PlatformSDK\Lib folder in Visual Studio 2008 ? 
I don't want to change my APIs and have the requirement to use glaux.h

as said [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/b66e5f7a-91f6-4dbe-b388-0c131008b08f) , does this work

> looks like glaux.lib is deprecated.
>   Instead link to kernel32.lib,
>   user32.lib, gdi32.lib and advapi32.lib

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Download gluax.h from http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/glaux.h
and gluax.lib from http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/glaux.lib.

Set the path and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, most programmers miss the **auxDIBImageLoad()** function, and there is no documented workaround. The glaux.lib is a static library and introduces some code bloat.

This image loader will work without <glaux.h>:

```
HBITMAP hbm=LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(1));
if (!hbm) return false;
BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbm,sizeof bm,&bm);
BITMAPINFO bmi={sizeof bmi,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,1,
  32};      // 24 = GL_BGR_EXT, 32 = GL_BGRA_EXT; all other fields are 0
DWORD*bits=new DWORD[bm.bmWidth*bm.bmHeight];
GetDIBits(hDC,hbm,0,bm.bmHeight,bits,&bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,3,bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,0,
  GL_BGRA_EXT,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,bits);
...
delete[] bits;
DeleteBitmap(hbm);
```

This routine will handle both RGB (24-bit) and indexed images correctly! No need for manual pixel twiddeling! The example loads from process.exe's resource with numeric ID 1.

The LoadBitmap() can be replaced by LoadImage() to load from a file.

If your input image is *known* to be of uncompressed RGB type, GetDIBits is not needed, as you can LoadImage() with LR_CREATEDIBSECTION, access the bits using the bmBits pointer, and use the **GL_BGR_EXT** constant. (**new** and **delete** operators are not needed.)

GetDIBits needs any valid device context handle to succeed. Use GetDC/ReleaseDC if you have no handle handy.

The **GL_BGRA_EXT** constant is a Microsoft extension to opengl, its use is exactly for such GetDIBits output.

Loading compressed PNG/GIF/JPG is not tested here but should work the same way; GetDIBits() is your friend.

Moreover, that bitmap can be selected into a memory device context (making it to a painting canvas) and then modified by plain old GDI functions, especially text writing functions, to insert text to the bitmap.